# Fitz removes page when inserting text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymupdf

I have a 2-page PDF, and when I try to insert text onto the last page, the page is getting removed. I believe the error is related to the PDF itself as the behavior is not consistent across all PDFs. But I am not sure what could be causing Fitz to remove the page.

The code to add text is as follows:

```
doc: fitz.Document = fitz.open(file_path)
page: fitz.Page = doc[doc.page_count - 1]
start_of_txt = fitz.Point(70, 90)  # X/Y coordinates
text = "INSERTED TEXT"

page.insert_text(
    start_of_txt,
    text,
    fontname="helv",
    fontsize=11,
    rotate=0,
    color=(0, 0, 0),  # font
doc.saveIncr()
```

What I figured out is if I do `doc.save()`, the missing page is there. Incremental save seems to remove the page.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to understand why this is or how I can do an incremental save?

Comment: Have you looked at [`Document.can_save_incrementally()`](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document.html#Document.can_save_incrementally)?

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to report suspected bugs here: please use the issue system of [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/).